# Fourier transform of Squared Sinc Function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, fourier-transform

I encountered a definite integral during my research:
$$\int^{Q_H}_{Q_L} \text{sinc}^2(aq) e^{2 \pi i \frac{
q\mathbf{x} \cdot (\mathbf{u_1} + \mathbf{u_2})}{N}} dq,$$
where $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{u_1},\mathbf{u_2}$ are 2D-vectors, and $q$ is a real number in the interval $［Q_L,Q_H］$

How can I do this integral? I think it is similar to Fourier transform with finite interval, but I am not sure.

Comment: Is the integral one-dimensional? Are the $Q_H$ and $Q_L$ just numbers? Etc? Can you clarify?

Comment: Yes, it's one dimensional and I have revised the question. Thanks

Comment: No closed-form. With $F(t)=\int_c^d sinc^2(q)e^{i tq}dq$ then $F''(t)=...$ you'll get that $F'(t)$ is a sine integral.

Comment: Is there an approximation for this integral? In my application, it's acceptable to sacrifice precision for calculation speed. For example, is it a good idea to replace squared sinc with a gaussian so that the integral has closed form?